# How to find searched words history in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I can't find searched words history in google anlitics statistics, I only see words during last 30 minutes
[google analytics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gw03s.png)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to change the date from datepicker (i.e. last 90 days) and with these interval the values ​​for the screenshot event are displayed.